# How do you declare an array that contains keys and values as strings and a key can have multiple values?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am practicing on a C programming exercise that asks to write a program simulating a short message service (SMS). The program lets the user to enter an abbreviated string such as "IMO", then a few full text are displayed; for example, "in my opinion", "international maritime organization", and "in memory of". I am considering of declaring an array that stores keys and values, but I don't know how to make a key to hold multiple values. I also want to hard code the sms dictionary, and number of keys and values, and theirs length are not fixed.

I already have this line in my program, but it doesn't satisfy my expectation.

```
char *dictionary[10][2]; // this code can only keep 10 keys and 10 values, and the length is defined to 10 characters.
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this but if the code you've accomplished so far is an indication, this exercise is beyond your abilities at this point. Your array should probably be an array of `struct`s with each `struct` containing a key and a list of translations for that key. The list could take several forms but the easiest would be an array of pointers to `char` arrays.

Comment: @CareyGregory I see your point. That's a great idea by using struct. Though I read "struct", this exercise wants me practice on pointer, array, and string library. Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Using an array of structs doesn't mean you're not focusing on pointers and arrays. The structs you need would almost certainly contain pointers and arrays. I would suggest giving it another effort using an array of structs and come back with a more detailed question if you get bogged down.

Comment: Can't I declare an array like this {{"omg", "oh my gosh", "oh my girl"}, {"luv", "love"}, {"AFAIK", "as far as i know"}} ?

Comment: @CareyGregory Ok I will use struct to make this exercise. I don't want to hurt myself.

Comment: Sure you can. You could solve this with a 3-dimension array, but most people find 3-D arrays more difficult to comprehend than structs.

Comment: I have thought of using 3-d array, but it is really confused me.

Comment: @CareyGregory Can I have you look at my solution? I have a problem with strcmp().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the line contains `strcmp()` doesn't return 0 for 2 equal strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DATAINPUTSIZE 180
#define STRUCTSIZE 10

struct TextStruct
{
    char * key;
    char * values;
    struct TextStruct *next;
};

typedef struct TextStruct TextStruct;

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    char *tokenPtr; // create char pointer
    char data_input[DATAINPUTSIZE];
    TextStruct sms1, sms2, sms3, sms4, sms5, sms6, sms7, sms8, sms9, sms10;
    TextStruct smsCases[] = 
    {
        {"AFAIK", "As far as I know", &sms1},
        {"AFK", "Away from keyboard", &sms2},
        {"LUV", "Love", &sms3},
        {"THX", "Thanks", &sms4},
        {"2day", "Today", &sms5},
        {"B4", "Before", &sms6},
        {"HAND", "Have a nice day", &sms7},
        {"CU", "See you", &sms8},
        {"SWYP?", "So what's your problem", &sms9},
        {"hh", "Haha", &sms10}
    };

    // Gets user's input
    puts("Enter a SMS (180 charaters exclusive): ");
    fgets(data_input,DATAINPUTSIZE,stdin);

    // Prints the string of data_input
    puts(data_input);

    // Tokenize the space characters; Compare each word if it is equal to keys (shortcut) of each struct
    // Tokenizing sentence
    tokenPtr = strtok(data_input, " ");

    // continue tokenizing sentence until tokenPtr becomes NULL
    while (tokenPtr != NULL)
    {
        //printf("%s\n", tokenPtr);
        for (i = 0; i < STRUCTSIZE; ++i)
        {
            if(strcmp(tokenPtr, smsCases[i].key) == 0)
            {
                puts(smsCases[i].values);
            }
        }
        tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " "); // get next token
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the problem. Because data_input array is containing '\n' character after user press Enter keyboard. Thus, this array has longer length than "key" string which doesn't has '\n' character.

Comment: You're getting there. The one thing you might want to change is to make the `values` element a linked list so you can have multiple definitions for one abbreviation. What you have now doesn't really accomplish that unless you make multiple entries for each abbreviation.